# How to get error Source(url) in componentDidCatch() in prod.env

Tags: reactjs

I'm using **componentDidCatch()** to catch error when react component have error,I want to report this error to my server with the error's .map file, but how can i get the **error Source** from **componentDidCatch()**?

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidCatch` takes two arguments `(error, errorInfo)`

So just add it as a parameter when declaring the function and you should have access to it.

`componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) { //do something with error }`

Comment: when I use window.onerror(), I can get error source like this:  

`window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) { ... }`,

so I can know which file this error from, but it seems like that cannot get Source from in componentDidCatch()